# Use systemd to stop one service while another runs

Tags: systemd

I'm setting up a systemd service to renew my SSL certificates from letsencrypt.  What I'd like to get working is for a systemd timer to stop the nginx service, run my certificate renewal script and then restart nginx.

Does systemd have some clever way of doing this?  Or do I just need to do the relevant stop and start action in the script itself?

Comment: Why do you need to stop the service ?

Comment: Because I'm using the letsencrypt standalone client, which needs to be able to listen on port 443 - which nginx holds open.  For various reasons, using the webroot client doesn't work for me.

Comment: If you really don't care about the downtime that your plan will cause, then you can certainly do that. But really, it's very easy to make standalone webroot work with nginx. You do not have to stop nginx at all.

Comment: You can renew the SSL certificates using Certbot and nginx without any downtime. You don't need the standalone client to listen on 443 for this. Then you can just reload nginx to pick up the new cert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does systemd have some clever way of doing this? Or do I just need to do the relevant stop and start action in the script itself?

No, there is no "clever way". Simply put

```
systemctl stop <whatever>
```

and

```
systemctl start <whatever>
```

in your renew script as necessary,

Answer (score 3):

Letsencrypt has a pre and post renewal hooks.

Adding this

```
[renewal-params]
# Other settings
pre-hook=systemctl stop <service name>
post-hook=systemctl start <service name>
```

to `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal/<domain name>.conf` will stop and start the service everytime you run `certbot renew`.

Answer (score -1):

If I understood correctly, you want to schedule nginx stop to reduce downtime.

I don't know about system D, but with any unix command you can use "at" to build your own command.

For example

```
echo "systemctll stop nginx && mv /etc/my/cert/new.cert && systemctll start nginx" | at -m 5:00
```

Comment: Since the question was specifically whether systemd has some way of handling this, this is not really an answer.

Comment: The edit doesn't really help - if I'm trying to use systemd timers, how is `at` involved?